# node.js CLI error

Tags: node.js, cmd

I have been using the node.js CLI for a while, and everything works just fine.

However, when I simply enter the command `node` into CMD, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\ander\>node
> bootstrap_node.js:158
              throw err;
              ^
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\ander\.node_repl_history'
    at Error (native)
```

I literally have no idea what to do... I've already tried reinstalling node.js and that hasn't helped.

Comment: @andersamer what if you "Run as Administrator" ?

Comment: I have run the `node` command in an elevated prompt